# Blank lines in txt files in Python

Tags: python, file, arduino

I want to write sensor values to a text file with Python. All is working fine but one thing; in the text file, there are blank lines between each value. It's really annoying because I can't put the values in a spreadsheet. It looks like this:

```
Sensor values:

2

4

6.32

1

etc....
```

When I want it without the line breaks:

```
Sensor values:
1
2
3
5
8
etc...
```

Here's the part of the code which writes the data to file:

```py
def write_data():
    global file_stream
    now = datetime.now()
    dt_string = now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H_%M_%S")
    file_stream = open("data " + dt_string+".txt", "w") # mode write ou append ?
    write_lines()

def write_lines():
    global after_id
    data = arduinoData.read()
    data2 = data.decode("utf-8")
    file_stream.write(data2)
    print(data2)
    if data2 == "F":
          print("Ca a marché")
           stopacq()
           return
    after_id = root.after(10, write_lines)
```

Comment: Can you include an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This way we can run your code without guessing what values are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the newline attribute

```
file_stream = open("data " + dt_string+".txt", "w", newline="")
```

Comment: Thanks you very much !

Comment: Learned something today!

Answer (score 0):

```
strip()
```

removes leading and trailing whitespace characters.

```
with open("directory/" + file, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        cleanedLine = line.strip()
        if cleanedLine: # is not empty
            print(cleanedLine)
```

Use the following command to get the text file:

```
python file.py > file.txt
```