# ruamel.yaml is munching quotes on string values

Tags: python, yaml

Have spent a while working around some of the dumping issues I had using Python ruaml.yaml module, but confused why this occurs. I am wanting to preserve comments and ordering to make it easier to hand edit the outputs later.

```
Description: "This is a string"
"""
import ruamel.yaml, sys

print(longline)
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(longline)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

program output:

```
Description: "This is a string"

Description: This is a string
```

It should be obvious, but I'm getting lost because I have had to hack around quite a few other issues where the YAML I am importing is a bit dirty, and extra carriage-returns around any comments were getting duplicated, so I had to remove them manually afterwards.

Comment: Looks like after some context, that this answers my quoting problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39262556/preserve-quotes-and-also-add-data-with-quotes-in-ruamel . Will have to ask the question about blank lines separately now that this makes more sense.

Comment: Solution for extra carriage-returns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60997312/blank-lines-in-txt-files-in-python/60998071#60998071

Comment: Thanks @Jens, will check that out. My Python coding is quite 'orrible, so debugging my problem was burning a lot of time - mostly with the input data being dirty, and trying to reformat the result so that the transformed diffs would not look crazy either.